# Android Application class doesn't save an instance of an object

Tags: android

I have a class named AppVariable which extends Application class

this is my AppVariable#OnCreate() method, and the getter and setter for the object i want to retrieve:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //set Facebook Manager
    setFacebookManager(new FacebookManager(this));
}

/**
 * Getter for FacebookManager Object
 * @return the FacebookConnectionManager object
 */
public FacebookManager getFacebookManager() {                           
    return this.facebookManager;
}

/**
 * Setter for FacebookManager object
 * @param facebookManager the new FacebookConnectionManager object
 */
public void setFacebookManager(FacebookManager facebookManager) {
    this.facebookManager = facebookManager;
}
```

inside my Activity i'm trying to get the FacebookManager object from the AppVariable object - but it always returns null:

```
    /**
     * Authorize with facebook
     */
    public void facebookAuthorization()
    {
        AppVaiable app = (AppVariables) getApplication();

           //Connecting with Facebook
        loadingStatus.setText("Connecting with Facebook");
        //authorize to Facebook             
        app.getFacebookManager().getFacebook().authorize(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facebookPermissions), new AuthorizeDialogListener(app));       
    }
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: If this is your code, and `facebookManager`
 is always `null`, then your app should always crash. Does your app crash? If so, what is the error log?

Comment: did you define your application object in your manifest file? And what does getApplication method do?

Comment: it does crush, saying the app.getFacebookManager().getFacbook().... have null pointer excepation

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your nullpointer is coming up at "app.getFacebookManager()". I would suggest that you print all the method outcomes and see where null is coming up from:

```
  Log.d("YourClass", "Manager: "+ app.getFacebookManager());
  Log.d("YourClass", "FAcebook: "+ app.getFacebookManager().getFacebook());
```

Comment: my understanding is that the above code is within one Activity?       try calling the facebookAuthorization just after where you are setting the instance setFacebookManager(new FacebookManager(this));